# How do I use OrderBy in my data on multiple fields?

Tags: c#, linq

Here is my code:

```
void Main() {
    List<Restaurant> RestaurantData = new List<Restaurant>();
}

class Restaurant {
    public int Id;
    public List<Complaint> ComplaintsList = new List<Complaints>();
}

class Complaint {
    public string Name;
    public string Address;
    public int Age;
    public DateTime ComplaintDate;
}

RestaurantData.OrderBy( x => x.ID, y => y.Complaint.Name).ToList();
```

I get an error on the `y => y.Complaint.Name` part.  Can someone please help me understand why?

I want to order the data by Restaurant ID, and then by the Name of the Complaint.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

After your edit, it appears that you want to Order the List first based on Restaurant.Id and then you want to order the inner list of `Complaint` based on `Name`. Following should do it.

```
List<Restaurant> newListOfRestaurant
        = RestaurantData
             .OrderBy(x => x.Id)
             .Select(r => new Restaurant
                  {
                      Id = r.Id,
                      ComplaintsList = r.ComplaintsList
                                        .OrderBy(c => c.Name)
                                        .ToList()
                  })
              .ToList();
```

---

*(Old Answer)*

You need to use [`Enumerable.ThenBy`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534743.aspx) if you want order on multiple fields.

> Performs a subsequent ordering of the elements in a sequence in
>   ascending order according to a key.

```
RestaurantData  = RestaurantData.OrderBy( x => x.ID)
                                .ThenBy(y => y.Complaint.Name)
                                .ToList();
```

You need to assign the result back to the `RestaurantData`, otherwise it will not modify the existing list.

Comment: Won't modify collection, orderby is useless here

Comment: @wudzik, yes I was adding that to the answer. Thanks.

Comment: I edited the code to reflect a new name 'ComplaintsList' (instead of Complaints).  Should your code then read '.ThenBy (y => y.ComplaintsList.Name)'?  I just want to make sure, as I am getting errors when compiling.

Comment: @phan, Your previous code in the question was not clear enough. Now since you have modified it, what exactly do you need ? Do you want to Order by Id first and then Order each List of complaint based on name ?

Comment: @Habib You're right, I wasn't clear.  Sorry for the iterative process but I myself was having a hard time figuring out how to communicate what I wanted.  You got it right (Order by ID first, then Order each List of Complaint based on name).  Thanks for being patient with me.

Answer (score 1):

**OrderBy does not modify collection**! Use ThenBy for multi field sorting

```
RestaurantData = RestaurantData.OrderBy( x => x.ID)
                       .ThenBy(y => y.Complaint.Name).ToList();
```

OrderBy is returing IOrderedEnumerable, read more about [OrderBy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966.aspx)

Comment: You should avoid overwriting the same variable by doing this. There is a reason why `OrderBy` does not modify the collection. =)

Comment: @rae1n linq is not changing collection, because it's just a query language :)

Comment: I was going for immutability and thread safety, but you got a point.

Answer (score 1):

The `OrderBy` only accepts a single property expression. To do multiple ones you must `ThenBy()` with other property expressions. Do,

```
 var restaurantsByIdThenByComplaintName = 
     RestaurantData
           .OrderBy(restaurant => restaurant.ID)
           .ThenBy(restaurant => restaurant.Complaint.Name)
           .ToList();
```

Since this returns a different list, I would advice using a different variable to avoid mutating state.

Comment: It won't order it at all. OrderBy is returning value, not modyfying

Comment: The OP did not mentioned modifying the original list.

Comment: So you won't point mistake? Calling OrderBy without assigning it to anything is pointless. It's like calling Sum() without assigning

Comment: Sorry, @wudzik, I was more concerned with actual syntax to do multiple order by since that was the original error OP reported. In any case, I've updated my answer...

Comment: wudzik is right, I made a mistake and do want to modify the original list.  It's my fault that I was not clear.